# Foutre quelqu'un au tapis

Tags: sens

I have heard the following dialogue in the TV series Marseille:

- Politician: De toute façon, t'as aucune chance.
- Mayor: Parce que je suis sorti de la campagne ? Attends que j'y revienne.
- Politician: Je vais aider Barrès à te foutre au tapis.

Context: The mayor of Marseille is negotiating with a politician his support in the municipal elections against his former ally and current opponent Lucas Barrès.

What does "foutre quelqu'un au tapis" mean? "to beat someone" (in the context of a competition) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Foutre au tapis* is slang for the expression *mettre au tapis* which means literally "to put someone on the carpet / on the floor" (i.e. to put someone down). It originates in combat sports such as boxing where when you are *au tapis*, the referee starts to count and you are out if you don't stand up before 10 is reached.

There is also *aller au tapis* which means to fall down in such a context.

Comment: I have never heard the expression "to put someone on the floor" in English. I assume the meaning of the French expression is "to beat someone" ?

Comment: That's the literal meaning, to put someone down if you prefer. It's different from to beat someone.